# Порядок выполнения PHP скриптов или как заблокировать повторное выполнение

Tags: php, блок

```
<?
//Проверяем на блокировку
if(file_exists("lock.txt"))
    die("Существует");
else
    echo "не существует";

//Блокируем
$h = fopen("lock.txt","w");
fclose($h);

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
    echo "test";
    sleep(10);
}

//Удаляем блокировку
unlink("lock.txt");
?>
```

Вопрос если при первой запущенной копии скрипта (он уже создал файл lock.txt), запустить его ещё раз, то вторая копия будет выполняться только после того, как 1 закончит свою работу. Грубо говоря - будет выведено 6 раз echo. А я ожидал, что если повторно запускаю скрипт и он видит файл с блокировкой, то он выходит по die.

1) Подскажите, из-за чего такое происходит?
2) Возможно ли прекращать выполнение второй запущенной копии, а не дожидаться её повторного выполнения.

Запускаю на Denwere

PHP Version 5.3.3


В FF 6.0.2 - глючит, Opera 11.51 - глючит. В IE 8 - работает.

**Вывод: В случае необходимости используем браузер IE :-)**

Comment: Как минимум, `fopen($name, "w")` не создает файл. Используйте "w+" или `file_put_contents($name, '')`.

Comment: Я обожаю когда начинающие разработчики чтото пишут и если у них что-то неработает сразу же выдумывают себе всяких страшностей :)<br>
Учитесь понимать то что вы пишете, как минимум проверили бы создается ли файл...

Comment: @Sh4dow 
>`'w'  Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

>`'w+'  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it

Comment: Или я 5 лет путал, или "w+" не отличается от "rw" O_O

Comment: я такие задачи решаю с помощью $_SESSION

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такая блокировка не надежная. Дело в том, что если в скрипте произойдет ошибка, либо если скрипт будет убит извне, то файл не будет удален и все последующие запуски будут безуспешными. Для того, что бы этого избежать необходимо использовать [flock()](http://php.net/flock). Алгоритм примерно следующий:

```
$lockFile = __FILE__.'.lock';
$hasFile = file_exists($lockFile);
$lockFp = fopen($lockFile, 'w');

// Если блокировку получить не удалось, значит второй скрипт еще работает
if (!flock($lockFp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    die('Sorry, one more script is running.');
}

// Если файл блокировки уже существовал, но не был залочен,
// значит предыдущий запуск завершился некорректно
if ($hasFile) {
    echo 'The previous running has been completed with an error.';
}

// Все в порядке, блокировка lock получен

// По окончании работы необходимо снять блокировку и удалить файл
register_shutdown_function(function() use ($lockFp, $lockFile) {
    flock($lockFp, LOCK_UN);
    unlink($lockFile);
});

// Дальше можем спокойно работать, не беспокоясь об повторном вызове
// Даже если скрипт умрет, со смертью процесса блокировка автоматически снимется
```

Что-же касается запуска долгоиграющих скриптов, то полноценных способов тут два:

1. Форкать/запускать еще один скрипт в отдельном процессе, а текущий завершать.
2. При использовании [PHP-FPM](http://php.net/install.fpm), вызывать функцию fastcgi_finish_request(). Тогда запрос корректно завершится, а скрипт продолжит работать сколько угодно долго.

Вариант-же с явной отправкой заголовка Content-Length, не очень хороший, поскольку:

1. Подходит только в случае если php работает через mod_php apache'а. Т.н. c nginx'ом такой фокус уже не прокатит.
2. Во некоторых браузерах соединение не будет закрыто и как следствие иконка загрузки страницы будет крутиться до тех пор пока скрипт окончательно не завершиться (или пока пользователь не нажмет кнопку Stop)

Answer (score 1):

Итак, проверил) Это действительно та же ситуация: FF висит, остальное нормально проходит. Переделка (результат смотрим в log.txt):

```
<?
//Проверяем на блокировку
if(file_exists("lock.txt"))
  die("copy");

function log123($msg) {
  if (!$f = fopen('log.txt', 'a+')) return false;
  @fputs($f, date('H:i:s > ').$msg."\r\n"));
  @fclose($f);
  return true;
  }

header('Content-Length: 1');
header('Connection: close;');
echo ' ';
@flush();
@ob_flush();

//Блокируем
@file_put_contents("lock.txt", "");

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
    log123("test"); // не используйте эхо, будет падать
    sleep(5);
}

//Удаляем блокировку
@unlink("lock.txt");
?>
```

Comment: Чтото мне все меньше нравится mazilla и все больше нравится chrome ^^

Comment: Что-то тоже глючит и не работает. В sleep попробуй побольше времени поставь, а то 1 скрипт к началу запуска второго может и прекратить свою работу :) И вот когда времени больше - 6 раз выводит test.

Comment: Проверил, да. Ща поковыряю. Собственно, смешно, что третий+ запросы отрабатывают как положено - сразу умирают с воплем "copy". Почему я и запостил - думал, второй просто глюкнул, а он так постоянно о_О 

Вариант "использовать ие для запуска" совсем не нравится?)

@korwru, могу специально под фф сделать грязный хак, но нужны сокеты. Интересует?)

Comment: @Sh4dow не, не надо).

Comment: А собственно этим хаком и решилось, откопал я тот скрипт... Глупая лисица =(

Суть в таком

    if (empty($_GET['confirm'])) { 
      // шлем запрос на себя с confirm=1
      exit;
      }

Answer (score 0):

require_once()/include_once() тут не спасет?

В вашем случае такое впечатление, что он файл НЕ создает вообще либо из-за работы mod_rewrite ищет не тот файл. 
Сказать сложно: в норме, код верный, вроде бы

Протестировать просто: закомменитируйте unlink().
Если и после этого запустится, то происходит то, что я написал, а если вылетит - проблема в sleep под виндой.

Comment: Если закомментить строку unlink("lock.txt");
то при повторном запуске... всё равно ждёт пока 1 копия выполнится, а затем умирает по die("Существует");<br />
1) Файл ищет тот.<br />
2) mod_rewrite тут имхо ни при чём.<br />
Вторая копия почему-то просто становится в "очередь" и ждёт завершения выполнения 1 копии.<br /><br />

<br />Про инклуд попробую, может получится через него.

Comment: @korwru, firefox?)

Comment: А причем тут firefox?O_o

Comment: А при том что у него какой-то шаманский глюк есть. Запрос на адрес - один и не больше. Я кучу времени угробил на отладку демона (просто запуская потоки из браузера), я я копался в реестре, в `about:config`, в его файлах, ставил плагины, шерстил mozilla.org. А потом открыл в ИЕ и запустил 5 потоков без проблем. Решилось, насколько я помню, отправкой "Content-Length: 0; Connection: close"

Comment: У меня тоже была страшная история - повисало все нафиг почемуто, суть  в том что был просто input с id, без тега форм и т.д., вообщем суть в том что в мазиле полностью ложился весь JS и перед каждой загрузкой страницы примерно минуту все висело, при этом в IE6 даже работало...<br>Решение удивило еще больше вместо <input> сделал <div><input></div>...<br>
А фразочку шаманский глюк в избраное 100% ^^